# Group data with id and get data from first and last row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, group-by

I have a database table `schedules`, which look like this:

[image]

Now, I am trying to get data such as:

```
----------------------------------------------
| id | bus_id | route | dept_time | arr_time |
----------------------------------------------
| 1 |    1    |  1, 4 | 07:00:59  | 23:30:30 |
----------------------------------------------
```

`route` is just the collection of station_id which can be indexed using `route_index.` When `arr_time` is `NULL`, its mean it is the `departing station` and when `dept_time` is `NULL`, its mean, it is the `destination`. I have group the route with this query:

```
SELECT id,bus_id,GROUP_CONCAT(station_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS route FROM schedules GROUP BY bus_id;
```

But I don't know how to get the `arr_time` and `dept_time` using this query. Also, how to get `station` names instead of id in this query. `Station` table only contains `(id and name)`.

Comment: If there is more than one route, what is the sense of having a single arr_time and dept_time? That's not a SQL issue - your example result data doesn't make real-world sense.

Comment: @faraday703 it is because there might be few stops in between. such as from start to dest, there are 2 stops, which will be ordered by route index and then those stops can have arr_time and depart_time.

Comment: Your data is not in a 'relational format' e.g. departure and arrival for the same trip is split across two rows. Consider using a spreadsheet to fix it e.g. formula to look at the row above. However, your `route` column (comma-separated string of `station_id` values) is again non-relational and will cause you problems when you later need to query the `station_id` values.

Comment: @onedaywhen.hi thanks for your comment. as i said earlier, trip will be divided among many stops, so that's why i split the rows. Is there any better solution for this one in your opinion? And I want comma seperated value to show on the UI, not for further processing, so that's why I am getting data in this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a join to translate station IDs to their names. As for the arrival and departure times - it's a dirty trick, but since aggregate functions ignore `null`s, you can use `min`/`max` to get them:

```
SELECT   sch.bus_id,
         GROUP_CONCAT(st.name ORDER BY route_index SEPARATOR ', ') AS route,
         MIN(dept_time) AS dept_time,
         MAX(arr_time) AS arr_time
FROM     schedules sch
JOIN     stations st ON sch.station_id = st.id
GROUP BY bus_id;
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. I am getting error at 'order by'. If i remove that, i got the result what i want. Can you please check, if there is any error or mistake. Thank you.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed The `order by` clause should come before the `separator`, my bad. Edited and fixed - thanks for noticing!